# How use Steam API send TradeOffer?

Tags: steam

Steam provides the transaction related API for us but not a specific example of    address:https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService#Input, as is First try, I don't know how to send a request for quotation transaction.

Comment: Now I already know the API link for the steam transaction, but I don't know how to request the specific parameters. This is the link http://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/send/. Does anyone know this? I understand it's not good for you to help a random person on the Internet, but I really need help

Answer (score 7):

Sending trade offers is not supported by Steam API officially.

You basically need to call the url https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/send with some parameters (Its a POST request).

You need to know two things: SteamId (for example mine is: 68364320) and the token of the partner (for example mine is: CzTCv8JM).

**Headers**

- 'referer': 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner={{partnerId}}&token={{tradeOfferToken}}'

**Form parameters**

- 'sessionid': Session Id of the steamcommunity session
- 'serverid': I really dont know what this means, just set it to 1
- 'partner': SteamId
- 'tradeoffermessage': Message appended to trade offer
- 'json_tradeoffer': JSON of the offer (link)
- 'captcha': Leave empty
- 'trade_offer_create_params': Parameters which are needed if you dont have the partner in the friend list, see `tradeofferparams.json`
- 'tradeofferid_countered': Leave empty i guess for you

Now the necessary JSON's:

**tradeofferparams.json**

```
{  
  "trade_offer_access_token":"{{tradeToken}}"
}
```

**itemAsset.json** (needed in `json_tradeoffer.json`)

You can get those id's by requesting the users inventory + your inventory.

```
{  
  "appid":"appid",
  "contextid":"contextid",
  "amount":"1",
  "assetid":"assetid"
}
```

**json_tradeoffer.json**

```
{  
  "newversion":true,
  "version":4,
  "me":{  
    "assets":[  

    ],
    "currency":[  

    ],
    "ready":false
  },
  "them":{  
    "assets":[  

    ],
    "currency":[  

    ],
    "ready":false
  }
}
```

Leave currency empty. I guess it will never be used, assets is an array of  `itemAsset.json`.

For reference implementation lookup [steam-awesome](https://github.com/scholtzm/awesome-steam) which lists multiple repositories with reference implementations. Most popular is probably [node-steam-tradeoffer-manager](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-tradeoffer-manager) where you can find the send function in [this piece of code](https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-tradeoffer-manager/blob/master/lib/classes/TradeOffer.js#L275).

Comment: Thank you, but I sent the request in this way. The result is null. Do you know why?

Comment: I cant tell you this without some information. What programming language are you using though? Probably there is an example already for this language which i can refer to.

Comment: Now I know why I returned to null because the Cookie is incomplete and the transaction can be sent, but to confirm the delivery via the phone, I need to do it without using the phone to confirm the direct transmission. I use Java

Comment: @user8288081 it's probably because the users profile is private. I had this issue before

Comment: this "null" isn't actually null, but its string written null in html body response. somebody coped with that?

Comment: Could you explain where to get data about that?... very unclear answer.
Where to get SteamID and token of partner?

Comment: How do I put items to the trade offer?

Comment: Where do I place tradeofferparams.json?? from your answer it seems that json_tradeoffer.json is a parent object