# How to send Steam Trade offer via native HTTP request?

Tags: http, steam, steam-web-api

I am using following answer on the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/45099695/12276316 .
But this answer is very unclear how to get those values I need.

1. *SteamId (for example mine is: 68364320)*. How do I get it? Is it enough to take id from my steam profile url?
2. *the token of the partner*. What is that? How do I get it?
3. *'sessionid': Session Id of the steamcommunity session .* How to get it?
4. *'serverid': I really don't know what this means, just set it to 1.* Fine
5. *'tradeoffermessage'*: Message appended to trade offer. What to do here?
6. *'json_tradeoffer'*: JSON of the offer (link). Same
7. *'referer': 'https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner={{partnerId}}&token={{tradeOfferToken}}'* Where to get tradeOfferToken?

And some jsons... That are very unclear
3 different request bodies for a single endpoint without any explanation which one to use for a simple trade offer request...

Could you share some information how to get those variables to test the trade offer request?

**UPD.**
What have I tried and what I found already:

POST request `https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/send?key='Steam API Key'`

Header:
`'referer': {myTradeOfferLink}` provided from Steam application.

Request body:

```
{  
  "newversion":true,
  "version":4,
  "me":{  
    "assets":[  
        {
            "appid": 570,
            "contextid": "2",
            "assetid": "14997054507",
            "classid": "996698558",
            "instanceid": "5383975481",
            "amount": "1"
        }
    ],
    "currency":[  

    ],
    "ready":false
  },
  "them":{  
    "assets":[  

    ],
    "currency":[  

    ],
    "ready":false
  }
}
```

I've got 401 Unauthorized. Response body is null

Answer (score 0):

```
401 Unauthorized
```

It means you haven't got an auth cookie for this request.
Before creating a trade offer you must log in to Steam.

I've already developed
[Java Lib for accepting and sending trades](https://github.com/wonderf/steam-trade-library)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the most important part: the login :-)

```
[2023-10-31 17:37:31.186549]: constructed query to https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/send
...
[2023-10-31 17:37:31.241777]: outgoing headers: [Referer: https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new?partner=...], [Content-Length: 568], [Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded], [Cookie: timezoneOffset=3600,0;steamLoginSecure=...;sessionid=...], [Host: steamcommunity.com], [User-Agent: Boost.Beast/345], [Accept-Language: en-US; q=0.9, en; q=0.8]
```

`sessionid` is the easiest part: you take your SteamID (Steam64), and base64-encode it.

`trade_offer_token` is something you normally query from Steam. On a client, this uses the unified messaging system to invoke the `Econ.GetTradeOfferAccessToken` service call; what this means for a web-app, I don't know.
It's been a while since I made this code, but a quick look at it suggests it's actually your own token since the call has no significant parameters.

`steamLoginSecure` is more advanced, to say the least. It's constructed from your SteamID again, and from an "access token". I'll actually NOT describe the login process here; that would be a rather lengthy paper, and I only do client-logins, not web-logins myself so I don't even know whether the same overall process applies to web-logins.

However, I have noticed a `steamLoginSecure` cookie -- with some luck, lifting it from your browser might do the trick. Unfortunately, access tokens have a comparatively short lifetime (a day or so), so even if it works it's probably not going to be a useful solution in the long run; you'll have to find out how Steams weblogins work so you can create you own cookie as needed...

Note: the access token has multiple components separated by "." characters. Take the 2nd component and base-64 decode it to get some json; the "exp" field is the expiration as a unix timestamp. So you can, at least, check whether you're working with a token that's still valid :-)

Comment: It might be hard for people like me who have worked with it for the first time. I understood how it is done only after I made a trade directly in the browser and analysed the request itself. But I have a question for you. Am I right that I need to authorise my bot in Steam and get all the cookies, then put them in the cookie parameter in the header and make a trade request?